# What's the connection of string_view and basic_string<char> and why does string_view example code not work?

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c++20, wsl-2, string-view

I have copied code from Bjarne Stroustrup's *A Tour of C++* to test out string views but I keep getting error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type
```

I am using VS Code `WSL 2` with `Ubuntu 20.04` and `gcc-11`

in `main.cpp`, I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "strings.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string king = "Harold";
    auto s1 = cat(king, "William");
}
```

in `strings.h`, I have the following. The function is copied as in the text book. I typed it out to avoid the peculiar `*` character that had a different encoding.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string cat(string_view sv1, string_view sv2) {
    string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());
    char* p = &res[0];

    for (char c : sv1)                  // one way
        *p++ = c;
    copy(sv2.begin(), sv2.end(), p);    // another way
    return res;
}
```

Using the `Ctrl+F5` command gives this error.

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
strings.h: In function ‘std::string cat(std::string_view, std::string_view)’:
strings.h:7:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type)’
    7 |     string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());
      |                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:650:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _Tp&, const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
  650 |         basic_string(const _Tp& __t, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:650:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/exception:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
```

I took a screenshot of what I see from Visual Studio code to indicate the underlined code, which doesn't makes

[image: Image view of the error in VS Code]

I thought it might have been the code editor but [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d7nrPhG8P) shows similar errors.

Since this is related to Vs Code, here are my

`launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-11 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-11 build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

and `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed the full line from the book? I don't see this listed in the errata.

Comment: What are you expecting `string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());` to do? What would you expect `string res(10);` to do?

Comment: @RetiredNinja One would expect it to do the same as `std::vector` and resize the string to size `10`. Interesting if this mistake is really in the book...

Comment: @user17732522 One might, but when given a clear "There's no such constructor" error one might check some documentation and discover `std::string(size_t, char)`. It does appear to be in the book: https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Tour_of_C++/jkRmDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=tour+of+C%2B%2B+string_view&pg=PT117&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @chris, there are other lines but I started off with just the first one to figure out what the error might be.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I expect, as the book implies, to be able to work with different string representations and concatenate them to produce a new string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with c++20. string_view was new in c++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be wrong.

The line

```
string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());
```

should be

```
string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length(), '\0');
```

---

`std::string` doesn't have a constructor which takes only a size argument, in contrast to `std::vector`. The value with which the elements are to be initialized must be provided explicitly.

---

I couldn't find this mistake in the list of errata [here](https://www.stroustrup.com/tour2_errata.html), though.